# What is causing a nil object at objects[0] when access to object is synchronized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization

We're getting the following exception when we call `[self.sessions allValues]`. Anywhere we are using sessions, we are also syncing on the lock object mutex.  What would cause this exception?

`[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]`

```
0   CoreFoundation 0x334ff987 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x331b449d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33487bf7 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 270
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3349730d +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 32
4   CoreFoundation                      0x334a16e7 -[NSDictionary allValues] + 282

@synchronized (mutex) {
    if (!self.sessions) {
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    NSMutableArray* activeSessions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (id<AccountSession> session in [self.sessions allValues]) {
        if (session) {
            [activeSessions addObject:session]; 
        }
    }

    return [activeSessions autorelease];
}
```

Comment: How is your mutex initialized?

Comment: The mutex is created in the init:  mutex = [[NSObject alloc] init];

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a sentinel nil in your call to `initWithObjects:count:`? E.g. `[NSArray initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil count:3]`.

Comment: @Fabian the `initWithObjects:count:` is called by `[NSDictionary allValues]` internally, so I would assume the code is fine, but there might be a problem with the objects itself (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One guess is:

Your session Dictionary contains key/values (=session instances). While adding them to the Dictionary, the keys and values are retained. If there is a memory issue with the session instance added to the dictionary - e.g. it accidently gets overreleased - you could end up with an invalid session instance which finally causes the exception. So you should check your memory management for the session objects.

Comment: Let's assume I did have a memory issue with overreleasing.  Would that actually cause this exception?  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I was thinking of a way to end up with a nil pointer within the dictionary. Overreleasing will not directly produce this, so my guess might not be correct. Do you somewhere use low level functions for manipulating memory which could cause mixup of the internal C-Array within the NSDictionary?